# Debugging iOS/Android with Flash Builder 4.6 and CS6?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I’m a little confused about the best way to debug my app.

When I’m developing for web/desktop- I simply hit “debug” in flash builder and I can see all my trace statements, etc. Now I want to port it to iOS and use gyroscope, accelerometer and so on for controls.

What is the fastest way to test this as a developer? I’m not so interested in deep internals (like ram use, framerate, so on). I just want to move around an iPad emulator and view trace statements so I can make the controls… but apparently Device Central is gone in CS6

I’ve seen screenshots of the emulator in Flash Pro CS6- but this strikes me as a bit weird… as though I’m supposed to use Flash Pro for development? Or does the emulator there link up with Flash Builder somehow?

Maybe it’s just my workflow, but exporting to an IPA and moving it to the device is way too slow of a bottleneck for this stage of the development (yes- later on, for tweaking, it’s important to test on the real device… but for now I just want to rapidly switch back and forth between code and test)

Comment: Thinks like the gyroscope and accelerometer cannot be tested with Flash Builder's adl device simulator. For that you have to use an actual device. And as of yet (Air 3.3) there is no way to speed up the process of ipa packaging and deploying it to the device via iPhone config util or iTunes. That's supposed to change with Air 3.4, but the packaging process will still need a lot of time as the packaging process isn't multithreaded.

Comment: Is there any way to leverage Flash Pro's device simulator, even though I'm coding with Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you debug your app from flash builder in an ios device, you will receive all your trace notifications on the console. Once the app is build, flash builder will prompt you to install it on your ios device and as soon you run it, your traces will start to appear.

You will also need an Apple certificate and an ad-hoc provisioning file to do it.

Comment: Would be much nicer if I could use an EMU... but this will do for now I guess :)

Comment: from AIR 3.4 on you can skip this step, see more at http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/air3-4/

Comment: I don't see anything there about an EMU? (specifically trying to test gyroscope stuff)

Comment: oh, sorry! I meant for the debugging process you wont need to go through iTunes anymore... as for gyroscope and accelerometer, this is hardware related so you probably wont be able to test it locally even if computer may have accelerometer as macbook pro does...

Comment: Is this still valid? How do we debug on IOS using Flash cs6 as an IDE?